# How to authenticate ldap in bash?

Tags: bash, ldap

I am writing a bash script that needs ldap authenticate to do the next steps. However, I have not found a tool that can auth ldap and return whether the username and password are true. Is there a existing program that can help me do this?

The script is like

```
read USERNAME
read -s PASSWD
LDAP_AUTH_RESULT="$(<ldapauth> <USERNAME> <PASSWD/prompt-passwd>)"
if [[ $LDAP_AUTH_RESULT == "$SUCCESS_FLAG" ]]; then
<things to do>
fi
```

Comment: If all you're doing for your authentication is to see if the username/password is valid in AD, you can use `ldapsearch` and see what the return code is. A result of `0` means a successfull connection. Are you saying that once authenticated, the commands need to run as the authenticated user?

Comment: @cutrightjm I only need to verify whether the username and password are correct. The following commands will be run by the original user.

Comment: I used `ldapsearch -x -s sub "uid=<username> -W"` to try to authenticate, but it seems that it is requiring the password of LDAP admin, instead of the specified user's.

Comment: Try this syntax, substituting everything after `CN=` to your account's AD CN. `ldapsearch -d -1 -x -H ldaps://dc1.domain.co.uk -D "CN=username,OU=ou-to-use,DC=domain,DC=com"`

Comment: @cutrightjm This command works, thanks. But on our ldap server, CN is full name such as "CN=John Smith" (and "uid=john"). Is it possible to specify the username with uid?

Comment: Currently I think I can use `ldapsearch -x -s sub "uid=john" | grep cn:` and get the full(CN) name in next steps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @cutrightjm for your hints in the comment. Current I am using such script

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Enter LDAP Username:"
read USERNAME
DN=$(ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap.example.com -s sub "uid=${USERNAME}" | grep 'dn: ' | sed 's/dn: //g')
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.example.com -D "${DN}" -W > /dev/null
EXITCODE=$?
if [[ ${EXITCODE} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Auth success"
else
    echo "Auth failed"
    exit ${EXITCODE}
fi
```

It is tested to work, but I am not sure whether there are any security issues.

Comment: Minor improvement... `printf ; read` can be `read -p "Enter LDAP Username: " USERNAME`, and your `grep | sed` can be replaced with `sed -n 's/^dn: //p'`. I'd recommend from a style perspective that all variables should be lowercase rather than uppercase.

Comment: Can you authenticate with `-D "$USERNAME"` or in your environment does it really need to be `-D "$DN"`?

Comment: @roaima `-D "$USERNAME"` does not work. It returns 34 with "invalid DN". I use Debian 10.

Comment: Ok that's fine. I use AD-based LDAP, which is different.